# Layout with cacheable="false" doesn't work in Magento Cloud with Fastly

Tags: magento2.4, full-page-cache, magento2-cloud, fastly

I am trying to make a whole custom controller not cacheable. In my layout XML I added this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="welcome.index" class="Vendor\Welcome\Block\Welcome\Index" template="Vendor_Welcome::welcome/index.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In my local, it works fine and the page is not coachable. However, when I upload it to our staging environment in Magento Cloud with Fastly enabled, it doesn't work and the page is stored in cache showing the info from another customer. Do I need to do something different to make that the **cacheable="false"** works with Fastly?

Comment: did you solve this? I'm also looking for a solution to this issue.